# Concat inside mybatis foreach

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm using mybatis in a Java Spring application and this is what I'm trying to do:

```xml
        WHERE
        <if test="param != null and param.size() > 0">
            AND pc.col ILIKE ANY (array
            <foreach item="it" collection="param" open="[" separator="," close="]">
                CONCAT('%', #{it}, '%')
            </foreach>
            )
        </if>
```

I'm trying to concat a value inside foreach but what's being passed to query is literally everythinng inside the foreach so it would be this:

> CONCAT('%', #{it}, '%')

How can I wrap the item with % inside the foreach?

Comment: What happens? If there is an error, include the full stack trace. If the final SQL is different from what you want, add 1) example parameter 2) expected final SQL and 3) actual SQL. To get 3), enable TRACE level logging.